# Creating Scatter Plot in R with multiple column

Tags: r

I am trying to create scatter plot with following  dataset can any one help me creating that.
My Dataset is like this:

```
Hour      WildBoar     Rodent    Human

01:00         2          3        0

02:00        5           5       2

03:00        3            2      1
```

Comment: You can check the `?pairs`

Comment: I recommend this for a good background of how to use `ggplot2`, which is a very popular way to visualize data in R:  http://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a time series data frame. When posting, make sure you specify what you are plotting against.

If you are making correlation biplots, `pairs(df)` where df is your data frame is what you want.

However if you want to plot WildBoar, Rodent, and Human against Hour, I would recomend reading Hadley's tidy data paper [here](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf).

here is some code to help get data tidy and ploted with ggplot2 package.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
#make data tidy
df <- melt(df, id.vars = "Hour")
#use ggplot
ggplot(df, aes(x = Hour, y = value, color = variable)) +
   geom_point()
```

There is lots you can do with ggplot2, and tones of resources, you can start [here](http://r-statistics.co/Complete-Ggplot2-Tutorial-Part1-With-R-Code.html) with some basics.